# Assertion issue with Artillery for Performance testing

Tags: performance-testing

I am not able to see the logging result, simply I want to see if response code assertion is working. I also dumped result in JSON but also not able to see assertion result

config:
target: "abc"
logging:
console: true
phases:
- duration: 1
arrivalRate: 10

scenarios:

- name: "API Load Test"
  flow:

  - post:
    url: "abc"
    json:
    email: "admin@abc.com"
    password: "Admin@123"
    name: "Login"
    hooks:
    afterResponse:

    - capture:

      - json: "$.statusCode"
        as: "statusCode"
    - |
      function assertStatusCode(requestParams, response, context, ee, next) {
      if (response.statusCode === 200) {
      console.log("Assertion passed: Status code is 200");
      } else {
      console.log("Assertion failed: Status code is not 200");
      }
      return next();
      }